# Why do libraries appear RED in Android Studio project view?

Tags: android, android-studio

I added the same libraries to two projects. In the one project, the libraries appear red in the project view and in the other project they appear black. Why do the libraries appear red?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the project is under revision control and the files appear red until committed.